# How to connect Focusrite scarlett 2i2 3rd gen to Behringer MS40 Studio monitors?

Tags: audio-interfaces, guitar, digital, analog, studio-monitors

Given below are images of the available hardware in my desk setup.

**PREVIOUS SETUP :**

1. Guitar plugged into focusrite through 9mm jack.
2. 2 9mm wire connected between Focusrite and JBL's ( TRS Balanced ) sockets.
3. Computer and Focusrite are plugged in with USB-C.

**QUESTION ON NEW SETUP :**

1. Based on BEHRINGER monitor (MS40) speaker's available input options in the back side, I have 3.5mm and RCA sockets. What is the best High quality option for me to connect Focusrite and Behringer MS40?
2. With 9mm TRS output available in Focusrite, how can i connect this audio interface with Behringer MS40 ?
3. Also added question on the DI, Can i add it between the audio interface and the guitar ? Based on previous usage i didnt find any difference in sound.

[image: Focusrite scarlett 2i2 3rd gen - Front]
[image: Focusrite scarlett 2i2 3rd gen - Back]
[image: Behringer MS40 - Front]
[image: Behringer MS40 - Back]
[image: Behringer DI - Front]
[image: Behringer DI - Back]
[image: JBL 104 BT - Front]
[image: JBL 104 BT - Back]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about sound design, but basic equipment connection.

Comment: This is the closest and most related community to ask questions about speaker setup. Do reconsider even though it's a basic question.

Comment: Many of us who write here answers as a hobby work also with electronics circuits and their designs. When we work with musicians we should remember that they want only to get the electronics to serve the music and start playing, recording, mixing etc... as soon as possible Most of them are not going to collect circuit knowledge more than what's needed for it. The questioner is here to collect his acute portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About DI-box: It's useless if your guitar stands the loading caused by your recording interface input. Low impedance inputs in many mixers easily cause treble loss if one connects an ordinary passive guitar output. Avoiding that harm needs either properly designed instrument input (=Hi-Z like guitar amp inputs) in the recording interface or active output in guitar. The Focusrite has the instrument input mode available, so use it when you record guitar or bass.

Behringer MS40 doesn't have a balanced input. In theory that's a limitation, but short (=2m or less) cables very likely do not collect too much noise. AC Power is not grounded, so you have chances to avoid ground loops which could cause harm as alternative noise collectors when one uses unbalanced audio connections.

You need special cable which has a TRS plug in other end and a RCA in the other end. Wiring:

- Plug sleeve to RCA cold
- Plug ring unconnected
- Plug tip to RCA RCA hot (=mid)

Focusrite surely stands connecting TS-plug to its output with no harm, so as well you can use a RCA cable with Phono-Plug adapter.

BTW 9mm is a wrong diameter, plugs are about 6,3 millimeters thick.

Comment: My guitar is schecter keith merrow KM7 mk iii standard telesto grey. And it has fishman fluence  active pickup. As you mentioned, is this ok to plug directly into interface for good quality ? I feel the cleans are distorting a little bit by connecting directly to the interface. Assuming my setup is correct. Just confirming....

Comment: Active pickup may overdrive the input, turn the guitar volume a little down. I do not have any modern high output active guitar, so I do not know if the distortion is generated already in the guitar. Check with high quality clean amp with low gain.